# Rack Application on routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What are the benefits of using the Rack application in routes instead of specifying action? And I am not able to understand how the route is working in the below code.

```
match '/admin', to: AdminApp, via: :all
```

I know this much. That if Url is `localhost/admin` this URL will match. And `via` is for HTTP verbs. But what is `AdminApp` here and via doing?

Answer (score 0):

> What are the benefits of using the Rack application in routes instead of specifying action

They are two different things! An action is just one function to handle a specific route inside your main app. But mounting a rack app like you're showing is literally embedding a whole separate app (with its own routes, controllers, views etc) inside your original app! It can even be [not written in Rails but Sinatra for instance](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-to-share-a-session-between-sinatra-and-rails#:%7E:text=Mounting%20a%20Sinatra%20app%20via,is%20the%20way%20to%20go.), as long as the app you are mounting complies with Rack.

As for the `via: :all` , it means match all http request verbs (e.g GET,POST,PUT etc). https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints